# Why does wget use Firefox cookies to login on an authenticated webpage?

Tags: python, cookies, wget

I am trying to login on an authenticated webpage using the following code:

```
$workingDirectory/./pyt www.tczonline.ir

wget -q -P $workingDirectory/ --load-cookies=$workingDirectory/cookies.txt --save-cookies=$workingDirectory/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies http://  www.tczonline.ir/?m=user
```

In the first line, a python script extracts needed cookies from the cookies.sqlite file which firefox generates.

Well this works, but just until I log into the webpage manually with firefox.
If I am not logged in using firefox, this won't work.

Why does this happen?

Why doesn't wget work independently, without using firefox?

Answer (score 2):

`wget` **can** and **does** work independently of Firefox. You are telling it to load your Firefox cookies (`--load-cookies=$workingDirectory/cookies.txt`), so it does!

There are other options if you don't want to use Firefox. First of all, you can use cookies from other browsers, as long as they're in Netscape format (which is the majority). For IE, you can use export cookies by `File > Import and Export > Export Cookies` and point `wget` to its location.

You are also free NOT to use any browser cookies at all. `wget` can handle saving and loading cookies on its own; you just have to tell it to do so:

```
# On the first run, we just save the cookie:
$ wget --post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' \
  --save-cookies /path/to/cookie_file.txt \
  --keep-session-cookies \
  www.tczonline.ir/login
```

Here, we are presumably submitting `foo` as username and `bar` as password into the site's login form. The `--save-cookies` option, well... saves the cookies to the specified location. The `--keep-session-cookies` option additionally saves the session cookies so you can perform authentication-based activities. The session information will not be saved if you only use `--save-cookies`, but *with `--keep-session-cookies` option, multiple Wget runs are considered a single browser session as far as the site is concerned.*

```
# Now wget can load page(s) behind authenticated areas:
$ wget --load-cookies /path/to/cookie_file.txt \
  www.tczonline.ir/secret
```

[Read more about `wget`'s HTTP options](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html).

Comment: Well, Actually this doesn't work and this is strange. Therefore I tried to use firefox cookies and it brought up the mentioned problem. when I do this, it just redirects into a page, like when you have typed a wrong password.

Comment: Try to (1) visit the homepage, save cookies + session; (2) visit the login page; (3) post the login credentials; (4) access authenticated area. Load and save the cookies for each of these requests (except the first one where you're only saving the cookies). Depending on how the site is handling its sessions, you may need to retrace the exact same steps with `wget` as with a real browser. Another common issue is sites blocking logins from non-standard browsers (IE, FF, Chrome, etc), so you might have to spoof the user agent as well.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I couldn't make this work. Even tried with curl  but no use. weird!

Comment: I don't see a login form at `http://www.tczonline.ir/?m=user`. Where are you trying to log in to? Do you have a test account I can try?

Comment: Well actually the login form is at `http://www.tczonline.ir`. `http://www.tczonline.ir/?m=user` is the page in which I need some info from after login.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with wget only, you need to first send your credentials to the login page, then use the returned cookie for the next request. The page in your code uses a simple post request (no javascript etc.), so it wouldn't bee too difficult:

```
wget -q -O - \
    --load-cookies=$workingDirectory/cookies.txt \
    --save-cookies=$workingDirectory/cookies.txt \
    --keep-session-cookies \
    --post-data="mid=USERNAME&pwd=PASSWORD" \
    "http://www.tczonline.ir/?m=login&op=inc"
```

After that, the file `cookies.txt` should contain the session cookie and you can continue like you've shown above.

Comment: You cannot load and save cookies in the same request. Save first when authenticating, load on subsequent requests when browsing.

Comment: Yes, you can. `--load-cookies` only tell wget to load the cookies from a file at start, and `--save-cookies` tells it to save them at the end, the two options are independent of each other and _can_ be used thogether very well. Wouldn't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: I understand your point, but you're likely not going to have the cookies saved somewhere (therefore, unable to load them) if you haven't visited the site yet. This is what I meant, that you have to visit the site first to save the cookies, so that they're available to be loaded on later requests.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but specifying the cookie file doesn't hurt in this case either, wget simply ignores it if it doesn't exist.